# Attribute error on keras on tensorflow

Tags: image, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

While using `Tensorflow v.1.0.1` and `Keras 2.0` and running this code:

```
from keras import backend as K
if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
input_shape = (1, img_width, img_height)
```

I'm getting the following error:

> AttributeError: module 'keras.backend' has no attribute
>   'image_data_format'

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

It's because `image_data_format` is defined in `keras.backend.common` in keras 2.0.

If you have an earlier version, you could try checking for the value of dim_ordering in your config file (default is tensorflow ordering `tf` corresponding to channels last).

Comment: Ok.. I am using keras 2.0 how to define it. from keras import backend as K... or from keras import backend.common?

Comment: Just do ```from keras.backend.common import image_forma_data```

Comment: Thanks Now I am getting error AttributeError: module 'keras.backend.common' has no attribute 'image_data_format'. and I am using keras 2.0

Comment: Ok Thanks I will do it

Comment: Thanks.. but again I am getting error.. my configuration is Successfully installed appdirs-1.4.3 keras-2.0.0 numpy-1.12.0 packaging-16.8 pbr-2.0.0 protobuf-3.2.0 pyparsing-2.2.0 pyyaml-3.12 setuptools-34.3.2 tensorflow-1.0.1                                                                                                                     ImportError: cannot import name 'image_format_data'
from keras.backend.common import image_data_format as k

ImportError: cannot import name 'image_data_format'

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to solve this

Solution 1 (if you are using tensorflow.keras)
`from tensorflow.keras import backend as K     #instead of from keras import backend as K`

Solution 2 (if you are using Keras directly)
`from keras import backend as K`
replace `K.image_data_format()` with `K.common.image_dim_ordering`

Answer (score 0):

In keras latest version i.e. keras == 2.4.3, I resolved this issue using below code

```
from keras.backend import image_data_format
```